# Time Complexity of Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: graph, dijkstra

I have seen in a lot of articles and here also that the time complexity of dijkstra is `O(V + ElogV)`
But shouldn't the time complexity be `O(V + ElogE)`?

here is my explanation

```
Set all nodes distance to infinity and source distance to 0 -> O(V) time
Add source node to priority queue

//priority queue will have a maximum of |E| elements and popping or inserting from priority queue                                                                                          
//is done in O(Log|E|) time. So the total complexity for the while loop is O(ElogE)

while the priority queue is not empty:
    pop min from the priority queue -> O(logE) time
    if the popped element is visited:
         continue
    else mark the popped element as visited
    for all edges from popped node (u, v, w):
         if dist[v] > dist[u] + w:
              dist[v] = dist[u] + w
              add (v, w) to the priority queue -> O(logE)
```

So shouldn't the time complexity be `O(V) + O(ElogE) = O(V + ElogE)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is assuming the runtime of `ExtractMin()` (or `pop min` as you called it) is `O(log E)` - but this one runs in `O(log V)`.

- ExtractMin with runtime `O(log V)` is called `|V|` times.
- For creating a Min-Heap, you need time `O(V)`.
- Each Decrease-Operation takes `O(log V)` time and there are `=<|E|` of those operations.

So runtime complexity is `O((V+E) log V)` which is `O(E log V)` (plus the time you need for initialization, so overall `O(V + E log V)`).

A more detailed analysis can be found in CLRS, chapter 24.3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that depends on your implementation. Looking at your pseudocode looks like you perform heappush() resulting in duplicate nodes with different distance values as opposed to implementations that perform a decrease operation i.e. they update the distance of node within the heap so the log(V) actually becomes log(E).